# How To Remove Import/Export Option From Tools?

Tags: admin, user-access

I want to give admin access to a freelancer. One plugin named controlled admin access done most of the part for me, expect it don't have option to select or deselect subtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the hook [admin_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/) and function [remove_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/)

The solution assumed the following conditions

- run it in theme functions.php, you may put somewhere else with different tweaking, but the following is proved to work in functions.php
- you know how to test the user access level by yourself, because the following solution is focus on removing the submenu only

```
function q364011_remove_tools_menu() {
    // you may add your access rights checking logic here with conditions and then do the following

    remove_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'export.php' );
    remove_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'import.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'q364011_remove_tools_menu' );
```